# wordpress nextGen gallery by code can not click next

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

i'am using wordpress and the nextGen Gallery plugin version 1.9.13 and i read out the galleries by code with this code:

```
$newnggShortcodes = new NextGEN_Shortcodes;
echo $newnggShortcodes->show_gallery( array("id"=>$currGalId,"template"=>"mygallery") );
```

this works fine, then i can click on the image and it pops up but then i can't click to next or previous image, it only pop up the one i have clicked.

when i check out the code, the rel tag is there, i looks like this:

```
<div id="ngg-gallery-10-112" class="ngg-galleryoverview">
<div id="ngg-image-256" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box">
<div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
<a class="cboxElement" rel="lightbox[set_10]" title=" " href="PATH-TO-IMAGE.jpg">
<img class="colorbox-manual" width="420" height="200" src="PATH-TO-IMAGE.jpg.jpg" alt="dsc_0007" title="dsc_0007">
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="ngg-image-257" class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail-box">
<div class="ngg-gallery-thumbnail">
<a class="cboxElement" rel="lightbox[set_10]" title=" " href="http://PATH-TO-IMAGE.jpg.jpg">
<img class="colorbox-manual" width="420" height="200" src="http://PATH-TO-IMAGE.jpg.jpg" alt="dsc_0008" title="dsc_0008">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

when i use the `[nggallery id=10]` in the backend, the it works fine.

anyone a idea?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake, the problem was not nextGen Gallery, the problem was that i use the jquery colorbox and the colorbox recognized it as single picture.